# build.gradle: all buildscript {} blocks must appear before any plugins {} blocks in the script

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle

My build.gradle file doesn't compile.
I have the following warning:

Build file 'C:\Users\User\AndroidStudioProjects**\build.gradle' line: 7

Could not compile build file 'C:\Users\User\AndroidStudioProjects**\build.gradle'.

> startup failed:
> build file 'C:\Users\User\AndroidStudioProjects**\build.gradle': 7: all buildscript {} blocks must appear before any plugins {} blocks in the script

This is my build.gradle code

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub- 
   projects/modules.
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.3.1' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.3.1' apply false
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you have a `plugins` block above your `buildscript` block if the error says you specifically cannot do that?